# Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7.3, getting PDO unexpected?

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

I have a Laravel 5.4 application, I had to move servers to a server with PHP 7.3. PDO is giving the above error. I worked in Php 7.2.7.

best I can see is this line generates the error

```
at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ?', array('email@server.fi'))
```

I am not sure what else would be helpful, did something change between 7.2 and 7.3 to cause such an error

Comment: Does your laravel version support php 7.3? i.e do `phpinfo()` in your public folder and see what it version it says

Comment: Interesting, good point to check, webserver is 7.0 and CLI is 7.3. I need to ask the host whats up with that. 

Anything else could be the issue? I read on another post if PHP version changes I should delete the vendor folder and reinstall

Comment: Yeah. Deleting any older versions of php and reinstalling laravel could help you out also. I'd say speak to the host first, up to you though